# Drawing diagonal lines on an UIView from both side

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift4

[image: Window grill]

create diagonal line from both side like window grill in swift.

How to design window grill for view programmatically(swift4)?

my wrong logic is given below which draw one side diagnal lines which crosses views.

```
        let height = view.frame.size.height
    let width  = view.frame.size.width
   let  space = 10
    for i in stride(from: 0, through: 2*Int(width), by: space) {
        view.layer.addSublayer(DesignShape.addLine(fromPoint: CGPoint(x:
            i, y: 0), toPoint: CGPoint(x:CGFloat(i-Int(width)), y: height), color: UIColor.black,lineWidth :2))
    }
```

**DesignShape.addLine** is method to draw line between two points using **UIBezierPaths**.

Comment: how about using simply an image asset as a background?

Comment: @MilanNosáľ view size is dynamic we need to design for universal  application

Comment: One way would be drawing it with UIBezierPaths, another would be an image which I think would be a better option.

Comment: @J.Doe i am using UIBezierPaths to draw lines but my logic is not working properly

Comment: You shouldn't add a shape layer for each line. Create **one** bezier path for **all** lines. Avoid unnecessary adding of layers. Why don't you create just a subclass of `UIView` and overwrite `drawRect:`?

Comment: Do u want this design with UIBeizerPath or Anyway ? [Without UIImage]

Comment: @McDonal_11 yes without image

Comment: I have updated my answer. If u r satisfy, kindly green tick and upvote it.

Comment: is my answer working ?

Comment: @McDonal_11 yes i am working on it to make dynamic based on view width and height(for counting grillCount), now it lefts some spaces in  last column and last row

Comment: I have did it dynamically

Comment: If u or ok.,, Kindly give green tick.

Comment: @McDonal_11 you given 17  grillCount static

Comment: It will work for, 11, 24, 35, 90, 1, 8, etc

Comment: U have to give count as u need.. It will work.

Comment: yes but i dont know real grill count  number , it must be depend  on view's height and width for complete cover that  no spaces left in that view

Comment: Ok.. but this will work, fine if u know three parametrs, Count, Width and Height..

Comment: yes but there is no count we have to set based on view' size

Comment: Give me full screen deign, i will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried that design with `UIBezierPath`. This may give some idea to your question.

**Coding**

```
@IBOutlet weak var shapeView: UIView!
// CONSTRAINTS top 20, left and right 16, height as 320

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   howManyGrillWeNeed(grillCount : 17, grillWidth: 40, grillHeight : 60)
}

func howManyGrillWeNeed(grillCount: Int, grillWidth: CGFloat, grillHeight: CGFloat)
{
    let xPositionDiff = Int((shapeView.frame.width / grillWidth))
    var xPosiitonCount : Int = 0
    var yPosiitonCount : Int = -1

    for i in 0..<grillCount
    {
        if i % xPositionDiff == 0
        {
            xPosiitonCount = 0
            yPosiitonCount = yPosiitonCount + 1
            print("newxLine")
        }
        else
        {
            xPosiitonCount = xPosiitonCount + 1
        }
        let grillVw = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: grillWidth, height: grillHeight))
        grillVw.backgroundColor = UIColor.white


        grillVw.frame.origin.x = CGFloat(xPosiitonCount) * grillWidth
        grillVw.frame.origin.y = CGFloat(yPosiitonCount) * grillHeight

        let layerWidth = grillWidth
        let layerHeight = grillHeight
        let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        bezierPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: layerHeight / 2))

        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: layerWidth / 2, y: 0))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: layerWidth, y: layerHeight / 2))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: layerWidth / 2, y: layerHeight))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: layerHeight / 2))


        // Mask to Path
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = bezierPath.cgPath
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.0

        grillVw.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        //grillVw.layer.mask = shapeLayer

        shapeView.addSubview(grillVw)
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image]